# Improving logic to find a group of characters in a string using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Experts,
I am a beginner in UNIX.

I have a file NewFile.txt which has the following content:

```
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 8 08:18:20 EDT 2014 (T76:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:1uh8fl:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26. Some text.
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 16 8:18:43 EDT 2014 (T76:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:y28z4v:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26. Some text.
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 8 8:18:46 EDT 2014 (T163:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:o16tk5:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26. Some text.
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 16 08:18:46 EDT 2014 (T163:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:o16tk5:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26.
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 16 08:18:47 EDT 2014 (T96:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:wgnsvv:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26.
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 16 08:18:48 EDT 2014 (T96:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:wgnsvv:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26.
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 16 08:19:19 EDT 2014 (T85:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:ogdu87:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26.
DBLogFile.txt:Fri May 16 08:19:48 EDT 2014 (T35:Partition:User:PasswordAdapter:ovfefb:buyerserver10) (jdbc:WARN) [ID6726]: Database connection pool size for database: Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param) exceeded 25 for connection Transaction.Schema1(DB details) (Login Param).  Current size is 26.
```

Basically the log writes a warning if the number of DB connection exceeds 25 and displays the current size.

I have the following code snippet to gather the DBLogFileName (`DBLogFile.txt`), Time (`Fri May 16 08:19:48 EDT 2014`) and current DB size (`26`)

```
while read -r line; do 

    echo "...........";

    COUNTSTR=`echo $line | awk -F "Current size is " '{print $2}'`;

    DBCOUNT=`echo $COUNTSTR | awk '{ print substr($1,0,2) }'`;

    echo DBCOUNT is $DBCOUNT;
    echo DBCOUNT is $DBCOUNT >> $LOGFILE;

    NODE=`echo $line | awk -F "Log.txt:" '{print $1}'`;

    echo NODE is $NODE;
    echo NODE is $NODE >> $LOGFILE;

    WHEN=`echo $line | awk -F "Log.txt:" '{print substr($2,0,28)}'`;

    echo WHEN is $WHEN;
    echo WHEN is WHEN >> $LOGFILE;

    echo "...........";

done < NewFile.txt
```

Am I adhering to the best practices of awk usage? Is there a way to improve this?
I am looking to gather: `filename, time and size`

Comment: No. shell is an environment from which to call tools with a programming language to just help you sequence those calls. The shell tool to parse text files is awk. Your whole script above should be 1 awk script, not a shell script with a few awk calls in it. So we can help you, update your question to show the expected output of your desired command given your posted input along with a brief description of the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this:

```
$ awk -v OFS=" - " '{
    split($1,a,/:/)
    name=a[1]
    time=a[2]" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6
    sub(/.*Current size is /,"")
    size=$1+0
    print name, time, size
}' file
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 8 08:18:20 EDT 2014 - 26
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 16 8:18:43 EDT 2014 - 26
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 8 8:18:46 EDT 2014 - 26
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 16 08:18:46 EDT 2014 - 26
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 16 08:18:47 EDT 2014 - 26
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 16 08:18:48 EDT 2014 - 26
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 16 08:19:19 EDT 2014 - 26
DBLogFile.txt - Fri May 16 08:19:48 EDT 2014 - 26
```

Is that close? What else do you need to make it do exactly what you want?

Comment: exactly, this is pretty close to what I want. Except that "print" which I hope we can modify 

Would you mind explaining the awk part what its doing? especially "size=$NF+0"? :)

Comment: NF is the number of fields in the line, $NF is therefore the last field. You can add 0 to turn it into a number. Although I don't see why this is necessary if you are just going to print it.

Comment: @JacobodeVera: Thanks for the expln. Thats helps. So I have to update the file information a little. It is not necessary that a line will end with "Current size is : 26" . There might be some text after that. In that case, how do we get "26"? Please suggest.

Comment: @JacobodeVera the line ended with `26.`, doing `$NF+0` strips the trailing `.`.

Comment: @KannanLg I modified the script based on your new input file. Now what?